# Fluid approximation for inflaton?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, cosmology, energy-conservation

In cosmology there is a widely used fluid approximation which applies when the mean free path is very small compared to the scale of observation and then all the properties of stress energy tensor can be described by energy density and pressure. So **I am wondering whether it is also true for inflaton and why?** It seems so since people can define density, pressure and even speed from the energy momentum tensor for inflaton as functions of coordinates. **And what about those matter contents with polarizations like photon?**

Also, **do we consider inflation to be adiabatic?** the equation of motion of inflaton can also be derived from the conservation equation of fluid $\dot{\rho}+3H(\rho+p)=0$ and the zero on the right hand side makes me assume so. Actually I am really confused about how to interpret the term **conservation** in this case. Even though the conservation of energy momentum of the universe as a whole $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$ must be true since the universe is closed or simply from Einstein equation, I couldn't make sense of the ever increasing total vacuum energy during inflation.

Any help would be appreciated!